# Странности Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Странное поведение Toolbar в активности.
При запуске приложения Toolbar выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При смене фрагментов в активности внешний вид Toolbar не изменяется. Изменяется только сабтитл. Изменение производится через Toolbar.setSubtitle().

Однако, после открытия другой активности (с данными, выбираемыми из списков), закрытия данной активности, и смены фрагмента, Toolbar принимает следующий вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В дальнейшем Toolbar остается в таком виде в не зависимости от операций.

Дополнительно:

1. Открываемая активность с данными имеет свойства:

   - android:windowBackground = @android:color/transparent
   - android:windowIsTranslucent = true

заданные через стили.

2. Если не производить ни каких изменений в Toolbar, его внешний вид не меняется ни при каких действиях.
3. Перезагрузка девайса и полная переустановка приложения не помогают.
4. compileSdkVersion 26

   buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

В чем может быть проблема?

ps: Лайоут активности.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription"
    tools:context="kz.nsk.insurance.user_client.ui.activity.WelcomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:background="@color/colorWindowsBackground"/>

    <ru.mdsps.view.orientalnavigation.OrientalNavigation
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorWindowsBackground"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:translationZ="2dp"
        app:onv_menu="@menu/main_navigation"
        app:onv_item_font_typeface="Museo"
        app:onv_item_color="@color/colorTextPrimary"
        app:onv_item_selected_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.Title.TextAppearance"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.SubTitle.TextAppearance"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/status_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OrientalNavigation - слегка модифицированный LinearLayout.

Смена фрагментов, как и смена сабтитла Toolbar производится из активити:

```
private void setupStartMode(int start_mode){
    Fragment frg = null;
    int titleRes = R.string.app_name;
    switch(start_mode){
        case CoreConst.ACTION_CODE_MY_ACCOUNT:
            titleRes = R.string.caption_main_drawer_menu_item_my_account;
            break;
        case CoreConst.ACTION_CODE_ARCHIVE_POLICIES:
            titleRes = R.string.caption_main_drawer_menu_item_archive_policies;
            frg = new MainPolicyArchiveFragment();
            break;
        case CoreConst.ACTION_CODE_ARCHIVE_INCIDENTS:
            titleRes = R.string.caption_main_drawer_menu_item_archive_incidents;
            frg = new MainIncidentArchiveFragment();
            break;
        case CoreConst.ACTION_CODE_EXIT_ACCOUNT:
            titleRes = R.string.caption_main_drawer_menu_item_exit_my_account;
            break;
        case CoreConst.ACTION_CODE_NEWS:
            titleRes = R.string.button_news;
            frg = new NewsListFragment();
            break;
        case CoreConst.ACTION_CODE_PRODUCTS:
            titleRes = R.string.button_products;
            frg = new ProductsListFragment();
            break;
        case CoreConst.ACTION_CODE_OFFICES:
            titleRes = R.string.button_offices;
            frg = new OfficesListFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_main_action_home:
            titleRes = R.string.menu_main_action_home;
            frg = new MainHomeFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_main_action_policy:
            titleRes = R.string.menu_main_action_policy;
            frg = new MainPolicyListFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_main_action_incident:
            titleRes = R.string.menu_main_action_incident;
            frg = new MainIncidentListFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_main_action_information:
            titleRes = R.string.menu_main_action_information;
            break;
    }

    mToolbar.setSubtitle(titleRes);

    if(frg != null){
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, frg)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

}
```

Проведен откат на buildToolsVersion "25.0.3" и компоненты 25.3.1 - не помогло :(

Comment: Похоже на багу либ гугла. Попробуйте числа из п4 до 25 понизить и либы гугла до той же версии.

Comment: покажите свой лейаут